# How to I update my trained space ner model with new training dataset?

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I'm new to nlp, I started learning how to train the custom ner in spacy.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
          ('what is the price of polo?', {'entities': [(21, 25, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of ball?', {'entities': [(21, 25, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of jegging?', {'entities': [(21, 28, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of t-shirt?', {'entities': [(21, 28, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of jeans?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of bat?', {'entities': [(21, 24, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of shirt?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of bag?', {'entities': [(21, 24, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of cup?', {'entities': [(21, 24, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of jug?', {'entities': [(21, 24, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of plate?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of glass?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of moniter?', {'entities': [(21, 28, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of desktop?', {'entities': [(21, 28, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of bottle?', {'entities': [(21, 27, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of mouse?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of keyboad?', {'entities': [(21, 28, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of chair?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of table?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]}), 
          ('what is the price of watch?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'Product')]})
]
```

Training the blank spacy model for the first time:

```
def train_spacy(data,iterations):
    TRAIN_DATA = data
    nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
    # create the built-in pipeline components and add them to the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
   

    # add labels
    for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
         for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
         ner.add_label(ent[2])

    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(iterations):
            print("Statring iteration " + str(itn))
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            losses = {}
            for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
                nlp.update(
                    [text],  # batch of texts
                    [annotations],  # batch of annotations
                    drop=0.2,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                    sgd=optimizer,  # callable to update weights
                    losses=losses)
            print(losses)
    return nlp


start_training = train_spacy(TRAIN_DATA, 20)
```

saving my trained spacy model:

```
# Saveing the trained model
start_training.to_disk("spacy_start_model")
```

my question here is how to update the saved model with new training data?
New training data:

```
TRAIN_DATA_2 = [('Who is Chaka Khan?', {"entities": [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),
            ('I like London and Berlin.', {"entities": [(7, 13, 'LOC')]})]
```

could any one help me with your solution and tip for this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you could retrain your model using your new data examples, but instead of starting from a blank model, you would now start from your existing model.

In order to achieve this, it will first remove the following line from your `train_spacy` method, and may be receives the model as a parameter:

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
```

Then to retrain your model instead of loading a spacy blank model and pass to your training method, load your existing model using the `load` method and then call your training method (read more about spacy save/load [here](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading)).

```
start_training = spacy.load("spacy_start_model")
```

One final suggestion, in my practice I have obtained better results by retraining a spacy NER model from an existing one such as `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg`, adding my custom entities, than training from scratch from a spacy blank model.

**ALL TOGETHER**:

1. Method update

```
def train_spacy(data, iterations, nlp):  # <-- Add model as nlp parameter
    TRAIN_DATA = data
    # create the built-in pipeline components and add them to the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
   

    # add labels
    for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
         for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
         ner.add_label(ent[2])

    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(iterations):
            print("Statring iteration " + str(itn))
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            losses = {}
            for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
                nlp.update(
                    [text],  # batch of texts
                    [annotations],  # batch of annotations
                    drop=0.2,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                    sgd=optimizer,  # callable to update weights
                    losses=losses)
            print(losses)
    return nlp

nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
start_training = train_spacy(TRAIN_DATA, 20, nlp)
```

2. Retrain your model

```
TRAIN_DATA_2 = [('Who is Chaka Khan?', {"entities": [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]}),
            ('I like London and Berlin.', {"entities": [(7, 13, 'LOC')]})]

nlp = spacy.load("spacy_start_model")  # <-- Now your base model is your custom model
start_training = train_spacy(TRAIN_DATA_2, 20, nlp)
```

I hopethis works for you!

Comment: while retraining the model, it will crash here ```ner.add_label(ent[2])``` as ```ner``` is not referenced before

Comment: I face this issue, so asked

Comment: You might try:
 
`LABEL = "LABEL_NAME"` 

`TRAIN_DATA = [ `
             `# LABEL_NAME`   
            `("some text with a thing", {"entities": [(0,9, "LABEL_NAME")]})]`   

`for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:`  
  `for ent in annotations.get("entities"):`  
    `#ner.add_label(ent[2])`  
    `**ner.add_label(LABEL)**`