# Improving accuracy of NER on Spacy for a tag that is not following one format

Tags: nlp, tags, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using Spacy model for NER on my datasets. It is showing poor tagging on B-Address and I-ADDRESS. The reason is because I have different type of address in my document. Some start with number, some start with name of building, some start with po box. Any idea how I can increase my accuracy on address tag?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two quick approaches that you can try with Spacy before moving on to something different:

1. **Re-train spacy NER with your custom examples:** If you have, for instance, a few hundred examples with real addresses, you can manually TAG it and then re-train the [spacy NER](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) to overfit your particular address. You can train a new NER from scratch or fine-tune an existing one. I recommend you start fine-tuning the "en_core_web_lg" NER. You can follow [the official documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training) on how to do so. Also, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70393614/7993163) to a different question can be of some help.
2. **A fixed Rules approach**: Spacy has a component called [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler),which allows you a rules-based matching over text. With this component and adding patterns using a Regex-like syntax, your model pipeline can recognize, for example, your particular ADDRESS. You can read more about this [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler).

I hope this helps you!

**EDIT**

@polm23 is right, EntityRuler isn't just Regex. I edited the answer and added more info about this component from official docs:

> The entity ruler lets you add spans to the Doc.ents using token-based rules or exact phrase matches. It can be combined with the statistical EntityRecognizer to boost accuracy, or used on its own to implement a purely rule-based entity recognition system. For usage examples, see the docs on [rule-based entity recognition](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler).

Comment: The EntityRuler/Matchers are not regexes. They support some regex based matching but they are more structured and work with multi-filed objects.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks